# How to filter jms message in apache camel xml configuration file

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, camel-jms

I wish to create jms subscriber on a general topic. to avoid unwanted messages i wish to create a filter there. the problem is the syntax is available every where from java code but I can not find how to do same in xml configuration file like blueprint.xml

Java code

```
String redSelector = "color='red'";
MessageConsumer redConsumer = redSession.createConsumer(queue, redSelector);
```

Apache camel route

```
<route id="externalNotificationsDispatchRoute" >
  <from uri="activemq:queue:{{vqueue.name}}" />
  .. filtering part
  <to uri="log:com?level=DEBUG" />
</route>
```

Answer (score 1):

JMS Message Selector is specified with `selector` URI parameter.

**Blueprint:**

```
<from uri="activemq:queue:{{vqueue.name}}?selector={{vqueue.selector}}" />
```

**Property file:**

```
vqueue.selector=color%3D'red'
```

Refer [JMS component documentation](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html) (ActiveMQ component iherits the parameters from the JMS component)

> **selector**
>
> Sets the JMS Selector, which is an SQL 92 predicate that is used to filter messages within the broker. You may have to encode special characters like '=' as %3D.